# Large number of short duration sessions after switching to "Manual session management" using google analytics iOS SDK

Tags: ios, session, google-analytics

**Problem**

On iOS we are using the latest version of Google Analytics SDK integrated via Cocoapods. Recently we switched to Manual session management as explained in their [SDK docs](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/sessions)
On looking into the GA dashboard we noticed that there is a huge drop in avg. session time. This is because now we are seeing majority of sessions with length in 1 to 10 seconds range.

Another thing we noticed is that there are more number of "Session Start" screen views than "Session End". See  **startAppSession** method below which is used to start/end a session with a screenView hit.

**Background Fetch**

We do have background fetch in our application. Is this could be the problem? We ruled out it as it use to be same when we had SDKs automatic session management/

application.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)

**Session time out setting**

The session time out setting in our dashboard = 30 minutes.

**Code sample for reference**

**Method to initialise the Google iOS SDK.**

```
  func setup() {
        let gai = GAI.sharedInstance()
        gai.dispatchInterval = 30
        let customDimensionOS = GAIFields.customDimension(for: 1)  
        let tracker = gai.tracker(withName: "master", trackingId: masterTrackingId)!
        tracker.set(customDimensionOS, value: deviceOS())
    }
```

**Method to start/end a session.**

```
func startAppSession(start:Bool) {
       let builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createScreenView()!
       tracker.set(kGAISessionControl, value: start ? "start" : "end")
       tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: start ? "Session Start" : "Session End")
       tracker.send(builder.build() as [NSObject : AnyObject])
       tracker.set(kGAISessionControl, value: nil)
}
```

**Start a session**
    From didFinishLaunchingWithOptions & applicationDidEnterBackground

```
func onApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification(_:Notification) {
        if let gai = GAI.sharedInstance() {
            gai.dispatchInterval = 30
        }
        sendAppSession(start: true)
       }
    }
```

**End a session** From applicationWillEnterForeground

```
    func onApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification(_:Notification) {

            sharedInstance.backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(withName: "Analytics.EndTimedEvents") {
                UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(sharedInstance.backgroundTask)
                sharedInstance.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
            }

            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                    sendAppSession(start: false)
                    UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(sharedInstance.backgroundTask)
                    sharedInstance.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
                    GADispatch()            
            }
        }
```

**Some relevant (but not exact) SO questions**

[Google Analytics iOS SDK “1 second sessions” (possibly background sessions?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37774306/google-analytics-ios-sdk-1-second-sessions-possibly-background-sessions)

[Session control with Google Analytics API v3 for iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855490/session-control-with-google-analytics-api-v3-for-ios?noredirect=1&lq=1)

**Google Issue tracker**

[Significant percentage of app sessions as 1 second](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35353792)